# Can operator+= make a call to itself but so that "*this" is swapped with "rhs"?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

EDIT: Thought I'd add this before responses... this is part of an assignment for a class so I have to stick with the underlying array and I have to stick with overloading the operators, none of that fancy templated jazzy stuff (that I wouldn't understand anyways).

EDIT2: I essentially want to take the call "A + B" but reverse it in my function so that it's "B + A"

My goal here is to minimize the amount of new memory allocations so I'd like to avoid this call to the copy constructor (the 'if' case) in the following method if possible:

```
Poly& Poly::operator+=(const Poly& rhs) {
    // actual addition of rhs to *this
    if (maxExponent < rhs.maxExponent) {
        Poly temp(rhs);

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxExponent; i++) {
            temp.polynomial[i] += polynomial[i];
        }

        *this = temp;
        //return *this;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= rhs.maxExponent; i++) {
            polynomial[i] += rhs.polynomial[i];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

I thought I was going to be a smartass and try this sneaky tactic... but I'm unable to get proper type conversions for it to work properly (if it's even possible):

```
Poly& Poly::operator+=(const Poly& rhs) {
    // actual addition of rhs to *this
    if (maxExponent < rhs.maxExponent) {
        return (rhs + *this);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= rhs.maxExponent; i++) {
            polynomial[i] += rhs.polynomial[i];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

My thought process is that basically by calling itself but switching the order of the params I can work directly with the rhs since it wont be const anymore and I won't even have to resize a new array. Here is my operator+ for reference since they work together:

```
inline Poly operator+(Poly lhs, const Poly& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Your second implementation would not work because it calls `operator+` which then calls `operator+=` and so on... Why not modify the `polynomial` member in the `if(true)` case directly as you do in the `else` case?

Comment: It also sounds like you're trying to violate the constness of the rhs. This doesn't sound like a valid thing to do.

Comment: @pmr: Actually, the second implementation will not work because it returns a reference to a temporary.  The recursion terminates just fine.

Comment: @pmr I can't modify the rhs there because it's a const... I essentially want to take the call A + B but reverse it in my function so that it's B + A.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
friend Poly operator+(T&& lhs, U&& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.maxExponent < rhs.maxExponent)
        return Poly(std::forward<U&&>(rhs)) += lhs;
    return Poly(std::forward<T&&>(lhs)) += rhs;
}
```

(By virtue of being a `friend`, it will be found only by argument-dependent lookup and only when an argument is a `Poly`.  You could augment that with some `enable_if`.)

(You can do it without templates too... but then you end up with four versions: `lhs` and `rhs` can be `const Poly&` or `Poly&&` and there are four combinations.  For some of these combinations there will be no benefit to the `std::forward`, but also no harm.)

To answer your question directly -- no, swapping `lhs` and `rhs` of `lhs += rhs` is a BAD idea.  `+=` is supposed to modify the object on the left-hand side and leave the right-hand side unchanged.  That implies that you can't steal resources from `rhs` (unless of course it is an rvalue reference.)

The one case `operator+=` can steal resources from `rhs` is when it is an rvalue reference, then:

```
Poly& Poly::operator+=(Poly&& rhs)
{
    if (maxExponent < rhs.maxExponent)
        swap(rhs);

    for (int i = 0; i <= rhs.maxExponent; i++) {
        polynomial[i] += rhs.polynomial[i];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: swap takes in 2 parameters and I'm not quite sure that would accomplish what I need because of this snippet taken from documentation: "Notice how this function involves a copy construction and two assignment operations"

I was hoping that I could essentially terminate the call and just "recall" it with the params swapped because to the user there would be absolutely no difference but underneath it would save on allocations.

Comment: That swap (assuming a member function) makes the addition rhs + rhs and a rvalue reference is useless in this context

Comment: @DieterLücking: take a closer look

Answer (score 1):

> My goal here is to minimize the amount of new memory allocations so I'd like to avoid this call to the copy constructor (the `if` case) in the following method if possible

Then simply don't create a temp `Poly` object to begin with.  In your `if(false)` case, you are modifying `lhs.polynomial` directly.  Do the same thing in the `if(true)` case as well.  The whole purpose of the `+=` operator is to modify `lhs` with the result of the addition, whereas the purpose of the `+` operator is to return a copy of the addition result without modifying `lhs`.

So try something like this:

```
Poly& Poly::operator+=(const Poly& rhs)
{
    int num = (maxExponent < rhs.maxExponent) ? maxExponent : rhs.maxExponent;
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    {
        polynomial[i] += rhs.polynomial[i];
    }
    //...
    return *this;
}

inline Poly operator+(Poly lhs, const Poly& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return temp;
}
```

**Update:** assuming you want to grow `lhs.polynomial` when `lhs.maxExponent < rhs.maxExponent`, but not shrink `lhs.polynomial` when `rhs.maxExponent < lhs.maxExponent`, then try something more like this:

```
Poly& Poly::operator+=(const Poly& rhs)
{
    if (maxExponent < rhs.maxExponent)
    {
        // not using copy constructor or assignment operator
        // to avoid allocating twice - one for the temp and
        // again for the assignment.  If using C++11, then
        // using a move assignment operator for a temp makes
        // more sense, as it involves only one allocation...

        int oldMaxExponent = maxExponent;
        int newMaxExponent = rhs.maxExponent;

        // resize this->polynomial to newMaxExponent length as needed...

        for (int i = 0; i <= oldMaxExponent; i++)
            polynomial[i] += rhs.polynomial[i];

        for (int i = oldMaxExponent+1; i <= newMaxExponent; i++)
            polynomial[i] = rhs.polynomial[i];

        maxExponent = newMaxExponent;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= rhs.maxExponent; i++)
            polynomial[i] += rhs.polynomial[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

inline Poly operator+(Poly lhs, const Poly& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain this above but maxExponent is also the size of the underlying array for each Poly. So if rhs.maxExponent is larger and you run the loop at that length then you'll run off the end of the lhs.polynomial[] and hit memory violations. So basically what needs to be done is to resize the array to the appropriate length (which is the length of rhs) which is why I call the copy constructor there.

Comment: I figured as much, so read my answer again more carefully. If `lhs.maxExponent` is less than `rhs.maxExponent` then the loop runs `lhs.maxExponent` times. If `rhs.maxExponent` is less than `lhs.maxExponent` then the loop runs `rhs.maxExponent` times. Either way, there is no array overflow since the lesser `maxExponent` is used for the loop counter and should always be in the range for `lhs.polynomial`.

Comment: As for resizing `lhs.polynomial`, I could see where `lhs.polynomial` might need to grow if `rhs.maxExponent > lhs.maxExponent` (your original code did that), but do you really want to shrink `lhs.polynomial` when `rhs.maxExponent < lhs.maxExponent` (your original code did not do that)? If so, then you cannot avoid a reallocation whenever `lhs.maxExplonent != rhs.maxExponent`.